# String in grails aren't strings?

Tags: string, grails

This error has happened to me countless times, and usually I find a way to not use Strings, but it's incredibly frustrating.

Every now and then an error such as this one occurs:

> Executing action [edit] of controller
>   [edu.drexel.goodwin.events.web.EventController]
>   caused exception:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method:
>   grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService.ifAllGranted()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values:
>   [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]"

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
springSecurityService.ifAllGranted(new String("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"))
```

I've also tried all of the following to no avail:

```
springSecurityService.ifAllGranted("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
springSecurityService.ifAllGranted("""ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN""")
springSecurityService.ifAllGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')
springSecurityService.ifAllGranted('''ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN''')
```

It's basically as if EVERY string variable is immediately turned into the value stored in the string... but how do you actually use string variables?

Thank you very much for your help,
-Asaf

Comment: Never use `new String(string)` - only create a new String when passing in a byte array. Strings are immutable and cached, so creating a new String instance with the same value as another is very wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im pretty sure the issue is not a String issue, its a "using the API incorrectly" issue.  Check the documentation:

http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html

Im not seeing `ifAllGranted` on the `SpringSecurityService` class.  I believe it used to be there in older versions of SpringSecurity (i.e. Acegi).

Try using `SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted` instead of springSecurityService.  If you are interested in how it works, use the source, luke.

```
/**
     * Check if the current user has all of the specified roles.
     * @param roles  a comma-delimited list of role names
     * @return <code>true</code> if the user is authenticated and has all the roles
     */
    public static boolean ifAllGranted(final String roles) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> inferred = findInferredAuthorities(getPrincipalAuthorities());
        return inferred.containsAll(parseAuthoritiesString(roles));
    }
```

Comment: Frustratingly though, I see this error over and over again... as in this case, the problem is often something else.  The error message isn't very helpful...

Comment: @asaf np, thats what we are here for.  As a note, its a groovy thing.  Because of groovy's loose typing, it tries to do what is right.  If it cant figure it out, thats the message you get.  In Java, it would be a compiler warning.  One of the tradeoffs of using Grails.

Comment: @Asaf Please consider accepting this answer if it has helped you solve your problem. See here for why this is important : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/ (You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer)